# ManyToMany fields are not showing in if statement in template

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, many-to-many

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to use `if statement` in template of `two many fields` BUT `if` statement is not working correctly.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Profile",blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='viewed_posts',editable=False)
```

views.py

```
def detail_view(request,pk,slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)

    friend = request.user.profile.friends.all()
    saw = post.viewers.all()

    context = {'friend':friend,'saw':saw}
```

template.html

```
{% if request.user.profile.friends.all in post.viewers.all %}

"SHOWING SOME TEXT"

{% endif %}
```

> I am trying to show if `request.user friends` are in `post viewers` then show some text.

- When i print `{{ request.user.profile.friends.all }}` it show friends of **request.user**, It works correctly.
- AND when i print `{{ post.viewers.all }}` then it correctly shows the post viewers (users).

When i try to print some text after combine both in `if` statement then it doesn't showing anything.

I have no idea where is the Mistake.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: What is your `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: What do you mean  ?

Comment: You are using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` and `User` at the same time. Are those different models?

Comment: I am using **User** for `post_owner` and `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` for **likes** .

Comment: Ok, but is that the same Model User?

Comment: YES, i guess...

Comment: You can't do that in template, you have to do that in the view.

Comment: BUT i have done it as i mentioned in the `question's view` . BUT still not working. AND also as @alv2017 said.

Comment: @Jhon `request.user.profile.friends.all in post.viewers.all` What do you want to do with this line? Check if **all** the users friends have viewed the post? OR check if **any** of the friends have seen the post?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I am trying to see `check if any of the friends have seen the post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` in the view:

```
def detail_view(request,pk,slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)

    friend = request.user.profile.friends.all()
    saw = post.viewers.all()

    seen_friends = post.viewers.filter(
        id__in=friend.values_list("user_id")
    ).exists()

    context = {
        'friend':friend,'saw':saw, 
        'seen_friends':seen_friends
    }
```

in template.html:

```
{% if seen_friends %}

"SHOWING SOME TEXT"

{% endif %}
```

Comment: I believe `post.viewers` will give the `User` model while `friends` is a many to many from  Profile to itself. That way the lookup should potentially be `profile_id__in=friend.values_list("user_id")`

Comment: It says **Cannot resolve keyword 'user_id' into field** AND i also tried by using **profile_id__in**. BUT still same error.

Comment: Sir, It is showing **Cannot resolve keyword 'profile_id' into field**

Comment: @Jhon, i guess it must be : `seen_friends = post.viewers.filter(
        id__in=friend.values_list("user_id")
    ).exists()` . I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
{% if request.user.profile.friends.all in post.viewers.all %}
```

**Update:**

The template has an access to request.user object, but not to the profile object. You are trying to apply Django ORM methods in the template, it is not going to work.

```
def detail_view(request,pk,slug):
    # some code
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context = {'profile':profile}
    # more code
    return render(request, template_file, context)
```

Comment: BUT how can i do it ? Do i need to change `ManyToMany field related with Profile` instead of  **User** ?

Comment: you have to do it in the view by passing in user's profile(s) as a context variable.

Comment: You mean like :- `request.user.profile` BUT then ? I have updated my views.

Comment: I created an example with passing profile to the view context, after that the profile variable will become available in the view template.

Comment: I did like :- `{% if profile.friends.all in post.viewers.all %}

"gggg"

{% endif %}` BUT still not working